# Jquery datepicker date range for 365 days

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am trying to restrict date range in jquery datepicker. Actually I have date range inputs like from_date and to_date I want to_date maxdate value should be the from_date + 365 days so it will be 1 year date range. I am not sure how to do this.

I tried this way but not working:

```
$(function() {
    $( "#from" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      minDate: 0,
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      onClose: function( selectedDate ) {
        $( "#to" ).datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate );
      }
    });
    $( "#to" ).datepicker({
      defaultDate: "+1w",
      changeMonth: true,
      numberOfMonths: 1,
      maxDate: new Date($('#from').val() + 365),
    });
  });
```

Comment: add maxDate: 365, in your jquery.

Comment: It should be start from the selected date in input #from + 365 days. If I will put maxDate: 365 it will count days from today instead of counting from #from input date selected. Got it ?

Comment: then subtract the selected date from today's date, to get number of days, and add 365.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set desired number of days in `days_to_add`. Also note, that you will probably want the `changeYear` option on.

```js
$(function () {
    $("#from").datepicker({
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        minDate: 0,
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        numberOfMonths: 1,
        onClose: function (selectedDate) {
            $("#to").datepicker("option", "minDate", selectedDate);

            var days_to_add = 365, // SET DAYS HERE
                parsed_date = new Date($.datepicker.parseDate('mm/dd/yy', selectedDate)),
                add_year = new Date(parsed_date.setDate(parsed_date.getDate() + days_to_add)),
                formatted_date = $.datepicker.formatDate('mm/dd/yy', add_year);

            $('#to').datepicker('option', 'maxDate', formatted_date);
        }
    });
    $("#to").datepicker({
        dateFormat: 'mm/dd/yy',
        defaultDate: "+1w",
        changeMonth: true,
        changeYear: true,
        maxDate: '+1y'
    });
});
```

```html
<link href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.4/themes/ui-lightness/jquery-ui.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.3/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>

<input id="from" />
<input id="to" />
```

Comment: Great its working fine. Its exactly what I was trying for. Thanks buddy.

Answer (score 0):

You can do it this way

```
$("#from").datepicker({
dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',
onSelect: function(dateStr) {
    var d = $.datepicker.parseDate('dd/mm/yy', dateStr);
    var years = parseInt(1);

    d.setFullYear(d.getFullYear() + years);
    d.setDate(d.getDate()-1);
    $('#to').datepicker({dateFormat: 'dd/mm/yy',maxDate: d});
}
});
```

Here is jsfiddle for it [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Dvd5C/312/)

Comment: Many thanks its working for me but still one problem. Let say I select in #from 20-Nov-2015 and in #to date it giving maxdate 20-Nov-2016 instead of 19-Nov-2016 because 20-Nov-2015 to 20-Nov-2016 it will be 366 days not 365 can we minus 1 days from max date please ?

Comment: can you tell me how please ?